# How can I import the github version of Golang Appengine because the version google.golang.org/appengine is outdated?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The repository at google.golang.org/appengine   is outdated( aetest package specifically), the most current version of aetest looks like it's at github.com/golang/appengine

I'm not sure how to propery import the repository code to my local computer because the import paths in the code repository are to an outdated repository.

I attempted:
$ go get github.com/golang/appengine

```
package github.com/golang/appengine: code in directory /Users/Bryan/work/gocode/src/github.com/golang/appengine expects import "google.golang.org/appengine"
```

So it looks like the code in the Github repository uses the old import path.

How should I properly import the most current version of golang appengine?

Comment: Other people will experience this same error when they attempt to follow the instructions on the Golang Appengine site. While the solution may be the same, a newb probably won't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the files from `$GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/appengine` to `$GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/appengine`, and use `google.golang.org/appengine` as the import path.

That, or go into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/appengine/doc.go` and delete the comment after `package appengine` in the file.

This is a result of [canonical import paths](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#canonicalimports) added in Go 1.4.

Comment: That is an very hacky solution.  I wish Google did a better job of keeping their repositories and Tutorial info both current.

Comment: Hacky for sure, but it's the only way with a canonical import path defined.  However, if you're using a vendoring tool (like Govendor), most let you define an alternate import path from the actual source URL, which would allow you, for example, to always update from the github URL, but store it in the `google.golang.orc/appengine` directory structure for proper importing.  We have to do this with apache's thrift library in our applications currently.